# Wordpress plugin URL rewrite

Tags: wordpress, plugins, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress plugin which enables me to add events to my website.

However the url structure is e.g.

domain.com/events/cat/event-name

I was looking into the plugin, however I was not able to locate the way how the plugin reacts to that request.

Thus comes my questions:

What different ways are there for a plugin to be called via a certain url structure (like above e.g. all urls which contain "/events/cat" belong to the plugin) ?

I was looking at my .htaccess file but it was unchanged, also i was looking if the plugin uses a

```
add_action('parse_request', 'handler_action');
```

But I couldnt find anything. Are there any other ways the plugin could be using?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Its probably using a custom post type using [register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function,
this will then build a new URL rewrite rule

The other possible method is by using [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

something like

```
add_action('init', 'your_plugin_rules');
function your_plugin_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule( "events/cat/(.+)/?$", 'index.php?events=$matches[1]', "top");
}
```

if you check and print the value of `$wp_rewrite` you can see all the rewrite rules

e.g.

```
add_action('wp_head', function() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    echo '</pre>', print_r( $wp_rewrite, 1 ), '</pre>';
});
```